# Matomo Instance Goals and Google Ads Conversions's difference

Tags: google-ads-api, matomo

Why there is a big difference between my Matomo Instance Goals and Google Ads conversions (i.e., my Matomo Goals are 98 while conversions in Google Ads are only 2)? I explored four to five search communities but didn't get a relatable solution to my problem.